# How to reference a Autofield from one model to another

Tags: django-models

I need some input about referring an Autofield into another model.

1. I tried making a foreign key, but I am not sure if the syntax is right

```
I have a main model class with id as Autofield

class Metadataform(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Authors_Name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

Then I have a upload class
(I basically want to fetch the same id from the main model into the Meta_id in the uploadmeta model)

class uploadmeta(models.Model):
      Meta_id = models.ForeignKey('Metadataform',on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True)
      Authors_Name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
      tar_gif = models.FileField(upload_to='mnt/storage/DB-Data/')

      def __str__(self):
      return self.Meta_id
```

Comment: This is indeed correct, although you do not need to add a primary key yourself. Django does that, and furthermore your code does not really follows the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is indeed correct, although you do not need to add a primary key yourself. Django does that. Furthermore your code does not really follows the naming conventions.

You can implement this as:

```
class MetadataForm(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)


class UploadMeta(models.Model):
      metadata_form = models.ForeignKey('MetadataForm', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
      tar_gif = models.FileField(upload_to='mnt/storage/DB-Data/')
```

Furthermore it might not make much sense to set `blank=True`. This means that by default that field will not show up in forms. `null=True` not be necessary as well, since that means you can add `None` (in the database `NULL`) to that field.

The `__str__` of a model typically includes some field value(s) of that model. Since by only using values from a `ForeignKey` relation, it means two or more `UploadMeta`s that have different values, have the same textual representation if these refer to the same `MetaDataForm`?

It is not very clear to me eather why you defined a field named `Authors_Name` in the `UploadMeta` as well. If that is the same as the `metadata_form`'s `author_name`, then you better do not include an extra one since that creates *data duplication*.

Perhaps it is better to make an `Author` model as well, and let `MetadataForm` refer through a `ForeignKey` to the author of that `MetadataForm` model.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I still could not resolve it rightly. I have a form which has id as Autofield and author name as charfield. After I fill the form and submit I want the page to be redirected to my upload page with the same ID and the Author name I fill in the form. Please let me know if i should post in any of the code here

Comment: The Authors_Name is fetched in the upload from the Main form after I submit. But i am not able to fetch the ID

Comment: @user11603936: why do you need to fetch the id? If you use a `ModelForm` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) Django does the processing for you.